# how to include only one file and ignore the rest of the directory in git

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitignore

I use `IntelliJ` IDE for development. In the `.idea` folder, there is a `workspace.xml` file which I want to version control. I don't want to version control the rest of the folder.

I have added the following rule in `.gitignore` but I still can't get to version control the file.

The rule I am using is `!code_relate/code/frontend/web/.idea/workspace.xml`

The `.gitignore` file is

```
#ignore files for web project - codingjedi\code_related\code\frontend\web

code_related/code/frontend/common/javascripts/vendor/jquery/jquery*.js
code_related/code/frontend/common/javascripts/vendor/jquery/jquery*.map
code_related/code/frontend/common/javascripts/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap*.map
code_related/code/frontend/common/javascripts/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap*.js
code_related/code/frontend/common/javascripts/vendor/bootstrap/popper*.js
code_related/code/frontend/common/css/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap*.map
code_related/code/frontend/common/css/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap*.css
code_related/code/frontend/common/javascripts/vendor/popper/umd/popper*.js
code_related/code/frontend/common/javascripts/vendor/popper/umd/popper*.map
code_related/code/frontend/web/ui/.gitignore
code_related/code/frontend/web/ui/.editorconfig
logs
project
target
tmp
.history
dist
.idea
*.iml
out
.idea_modules
.classpath
.project
RUNNING_PID
.settings
public
dist-server
out-tsc
node_modules

.c9
*.launch
*.sublime-workspace

# misc
.sass-cache
connect.lock
coverage
libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
testem.log
typings

# e2e
code_related/code/frontend/web/ui/e2e/*.js
code_related/code/frontend/web/ui/e2e/*.map

# System Files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db

#MS temp generated files for xls, doc etc.
~$*

#include these files though
!code_relate/code/frontend/web/.idea/workspace.xml
```

Comment: Is it a typo at the end here? `code_relate/code` != `code_related/code`

Comment: I must be missing a lot of context, because it seems the solution is to simply do `git add workspace.xml` and just not add everything else.  Why do you need to add everything else to .gitignore?  Just don't add it.

Answer (score 0):

In general this is solved by adding the directory to .gitignore *and* then **force-add** the file so that it is tracked from that moment on.